# Abnormally high temperature and fast fan speed at BIOS/Grub on Asus laptop after Ubuntu update

Tags: grub2, asus, bios, fan

My laptop is getting hot and the fan runs at abnormally high speed few seconds after I switch it on and before even getting into Grub (*insecure boot* text appears), the screen flickers at BIOS and Grub screen, it continues until the boot is complete. This happened after  updating Ubuntu 14.04, I had to disable secure boot as per Virtualbox's DKMS request, at boot it now says: *insecure boot* and I can't change it . Recently, I updated the BIOS but didn't notice any issue.

Any suggestions ?

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D':

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11cd
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    --
    01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11cd
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Laptop: Asus N550JV
Video adapter: dedicated Geforce 750M
OS: Ubuntu + Windows

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: There is a suggested edit to this question, and it looks like you forgot to log into your account before editing your question.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question? Are you using Ubuntu inside VB? Do you have dual-boot with Windows?